# Cannot use existing image as a featured image since 3.8.1 update

Tags: images

Since the 3.8.1 update i have been unable to use an existing image in my media galley as a featured image thumbnail on my blog.
I have to manually download, change the name, and re-upload the file in order to use it as a featured image.
Is this some type of corruption in the database? I'm going a bit bonkers trying to find the solution.
Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why/How are you unable to use it. Is there any error message?

Comment: No it is fine. I can create a new post, insert a newly uploaded image and it will show. But if i select a previously uploaded image (pre 3.8.1) then the image will not show up at all.

Comment: You need to clarify on "the image will not show up at all". What happens if you choose it. In detail.

Comment: When i create a new post and click on featured image. If i select an image from my media gallery and set as featured image it will show in the featured image box on the edit post page. But once i click on save/update it will not show up in my category lists next the post. It will just say image not available. http://www.elginmanagement.com/category/blog/

Answer (score 0):

So everything looks and works fine in the Backend, but doesn't display properly in the Frontend.

First thing to try is temporarily switch to one of the default themes (e.g.
Twenty Fourteen) to see if it is an issue with the theme.

If everything works with the default theme it is a theme issue. You can then either

- contact the theme author (which i recommend in this case)
- post the relevant code from the theme template file. This is just guessing and depends on the theme but your probably need to look for a section in archive.php where there is "the_post_thumbnail"

Comment: I have tried it on the 2014 theme and it appears ok. It shows both the older images and newly uploaded images too.

Comment: What code shall i upload, the functions.php file or something different?

Comment: Just clarified your options.

Comment: I have checked in archive.php but there is nothing there relating to thumbnails. Shall i check in category.php? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes. Or wherever the relevant code is. You can have a look at the Template Hierarchy for Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I have checked category.php, archive.php and index.php but none of them reference a thumbnail. In functions.php there is this code at the start though define('TT_ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME','admin');
define('TT_ADMIN_FOLDER_PATH',TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.TT_ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME.'/'); //admin folder path
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

set_post_thumbnail_size( 190, 140 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions  
add_image_size('homeslide', 960, 400, true ); //(cropped)
add_image_size('single-image', 700, 400, true ); //(cropped)

require_once (OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_URL . 'options-framework.php');

Comment: Ok a further update to this. If i try and view the old images on there own http://www.elginmanagement.com/introduction-fee-tell-a-friend-about-us-and-win-a-20-itunes-voucher/elginlogohi-medium/ it just says image cannot be displayed.